# boto3: StreamingBody [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, stream, boto3

I have a `StreamingBody` from s3 that needs to be opened for an extended period of time (due to high processing time and the files being very large). This occasionally causes the error `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`.

I am not sure what is causing it but here is the an excerpt:

```py
import boto3

def csv_stream(s3, key):
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Key=key)
    body = obj['Body']
    text = codecs.getreader('utf-8')(body)
    return csv.reader(text)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

for key in get_keys():
    for row in csv_stream(s3, key):
        do_long_transformations(row)
```

This job usually takes at least half a day to complete.
What would be the fix here, since restarting the job is always very expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a retry config seems to solve it

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(retries={'max_attempts': 3}))
```